# How to get $\mathbb{R}^2$ from this?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have a family of sets $(B_r)_{r>0}$  defined by
$$B_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, (x-3)^2+y^2<r^2\}.$$
Is $$\bigcup_{r>0}B_r =\mathbb{R}^2 $$

I try this : we always know that: $\bigcup B_r\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ but if we let $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we gat $(a-3)^2+b^2=r^2$ then  $(a,b)\in B_{r+\varepsilon}\subset \bigcup B_r$

Comment: Think about the sets geometrically. It should be clear.

Comment: What did you try so far? What do the individual sets $B_r$ look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B_r$ is a ball of radius $r$ around $(3,0)$.

So if you want it to include $(a,b)$ you need the radius $r$ to be larger than $d((a,b),(3,0)) = \sqrt{(a-3)^2+b^2}$.

where $d$ is the distance between two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))= \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 +(y_1-y_2)^2}$$

So, if you choose $r=2\sqrt{(a-3)^2+b^2}$ then by definition $(a,b)\in B_r$.

Comment: You probably want $(a,b)\in B_r$ in your last sentence.

Comment: @Christoph yes of course. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand? I try this : we always know that: $\bigcup B_r\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ but if we let $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we gat $(a-3)^2+b^2=r^2$ then  $(a,b)\in B_{r+\varepsilon}\subset \bigcup B_r$

Comment: @Vrouvrou if you mean $r+\varepsilon$ (not minus epsilon). So yes this works. I chose to take $2r$ instead of $r+\varepsilon$ but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Yanko i see your edit I understand thank you 